# URL Rewrite pattern to match folder only when NOT preceded by specific folder

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Excuse the poor title, but I'm not sure how to word this exactly. Here's my scenario:

I've got this pattern:

`(.*)MySpecialFolder(.*)`

That I need rewritten to:

`{R:1}MyOtherFolder/MySpecialFolder{R:2}`

So `http://localhost/MySpecialFolder/test.aspx` will be rewritten as `http://localhost/MyOtherFolder/MySpecialFolder/test.aspx`

The problem is that on the next request, it still tries to replace `MySpecialFolder` again so it becomes `http://localhost/MyOtherFolder/MyOtherFolder/MySpecialFolder/test.aspx`, and so on.

Is there a way I can update my regex pattern to say:

"Replace `MySpecialFolder` with `MyOtherFolder/MySpecialFolder` but ONLY when `MySpecialFolder` is not already preceded with `MyOtherFolder/`"? So basically if `MyOtherFolder/MySpecialFolder` is already in the path, it doesn't see that as a "match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to unmatch MyOtherFolder